# Recursive as_array for One-to-many relationships with Kohana 3 ORM

Tags: json, api, kohana-3, one-to-many, kohana-orm

To begin with I'd like to say I know how to create ugly solutions for my problem. I am searching good solutions and best practices :)

**How do I create deep hierarchial arrays (to json_encode later) from Kohana 3 ORM objects including related objects where the relation type is one-to-many?**

The problem is that the ORM->as_array() method does work recursively for the "has one" and "belongs to" relationships but will stop and force you to use ->find_all() manually when you encounter a "has many" relationship.

Say I am creating a JSON API REST server using Kohana 3 and the built in ORM.
When someone looks at this URL: www.example.com/api/user?id=5
They will be served a JSON object for the user where id=5.

These are the orm-models and the relations:

- **User** *belongs to* a **Country**
- **User** *has many* **Messages**.
- **Message** *belongs to* a **Category**

I would like this to work:

```
echo json_encode(
ORM::factory('user', 5)
->with('country')
->with('messages')
->with('messages:category')
->find()
->as_array()
);
```

and give me output like this:

```
{
    name: "John"
    age: 54,
    country_id: 5,
    country: {
        name: 'Sweden',
        code: 'SE'
    },
    messages: {
        {
            content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor...',
            category_id: 1,
            category: {...}
        },
        {
            content: 'Sit amet elit...',
            category_id: 2,
            category: {...}
        },
        {
            content: 'Consectetur ipsum dolor...',
            category_id: 3,
            category: {...}
        }
    }
}
```

BUT THAT WONT WORK.
This is all you would get:

```
{
    name: "John"
    age: 54,
    country_id: 5,
    country: {
        name: 'Sweden',
        code: 'SE'
    }
}
```

Has someone forked or extended the Kohana 3 ORM to support this kind functionality?
Does someone know of any good Kohana 3 api module that takes care of this issue for you somehow?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this using only the ORM.  This is the case for two reasons:

1. If a `message` has a relation for `category`, that usually means that `category` has a corresponding relation for the `messages` in the category.  If you want to get the `message` "in full" - i.e. including its category - let's say that you also want to get the `category` "in full" - i.e. including its messages.  This is obviously a very bad idea, as you could very easily design yourself into an infinite loop. In other words, if there was a magic "recurse all relations" capability, *how would it know when to stop recursing?*
2. All that the ORM is doing behind the scenes when you call `find()` is building a SQL query that returns a row of data from the database.  However, what you are trying to do is too complicated for a single query that returns a single row.  (There is a way to retrieve multiple rows as one row with comma-separated values in each field using [MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), but I guarantee you that it is not worth the trouble.)

For both of these reasons, the ORM's `with()` method only works on `belongs_to` (in your case, the `user`'s `country` and the `message`'s `category`).

One way to do this query is to break it up into three steps, like this:

```
// Step 1: Get the user
$user = ORM::factory('user', 5)
    ->with('country')
    ->find();

// Step 2: Get the messages
$user->messages
    ->with('category')
    ->find_all();

// Step 3: Make user and the messages into arrays.
// User is easy, but messages are a little harder
// because they need to turn
//     from "an object containing an array of objects"
//     into "an array of arrays."
$user_arr = $user->as_array();
$fixer = function($obj)
{
    return $obj->as_array();
};
$user_arr['messages'] = array_map($fixer, $user->messages->as_array());

// Now you can output it
echo json_encode($user_arr);
```